# Subsetting a datatable with 1:n

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

While mucking around with some data I encounter a problem with sub setting a data.table

Sample of my datatable

```
library(data.table)

datatab <- structure(list(a = c(183591969L, 183591969L, 183591984L, 183591727L, 
                     183591733L), b = c(183591984L, 183591985L, 183591985L, 183591729L, 
                                        183591737L)), .Names = c("a", "b"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
                                        ), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I simply try to split the whole thing with a variable like

```
a <- 2
datatab[1:a,]
```

but get the error

> Warning message: In 1:a : numerical expression has 5 elements: only
>   the first used

while

```
df <- as.data.frame(datatab)
df[1:a,]
```

and

```
datatab[1:2,]
```

work as expected.

Might be something obvious I didn't get. I guess it has something to do with the way the data.table library handles the data but I would appreciate if someone can clarify. As my real data is much larger I would like to avoid the `as.data.frame()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `a` as a parameter which happens to be a column of the `data.table`, use a different name for the parameter:

```
x <- 2
datatab[1:x,]

#           a         b
#1: 183591969 183591984
#2: 183591969 183591985
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's something I didn't think about at all. Thanks!

Comment: there is also new feature, `..a` which look for `a` variable in parent scope.